# Newtonsoft.Json fail to converting from JSON to ICollection<Object>

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

Hi I have the following JSON and want to deserialize to `ICollection<Location>`

> "\u0001[{\"Id\": 1, \"Name\": \"A-01\", \"Address\": \"aa\",
>   \"Children\": [{\"Id\": 2, \"Name\": \"A-01-01\", \"Address\": \"bb\",
>   \"Children\": [{\"Id\": 5, \"Name\": \"A-01-02-01\", \"Address\":
>   \"cc\"}]}, {\"Id\": 3, \"Name\": \"A-01-02\", \"Address\": \"dd\"}]},
>   {\"Id\": 4, \"Name\": \"B-01\", \"Address\": \"ee\", \"Children\":
>   [{\"Id\": 6, \"Name\": \"B-01-01\", \"Address\": \"ff\"}]}]"

readable JSON

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "A-01",
    "Address": "aa",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "A-01-01",
        "Address": "bb",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Id": 5,
            "Name": "A-01-02-01",
            "Address": "cc"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "A-01-02",
        "Address": "dd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "Name": "B-01",
    "Address": "ee",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Id": 6,
        "Name": "B-01-01",
        "Address": "ff"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Location Object

```
public class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

    public Location ParentLocation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Children")]
    public virtual ICollection<Location> ChildrenLocation { get; set; }

}
```

I try to test clean up string but no hope..

```
    var jsonString = @"[{""Id"":1,""Name"":""A-01"",""Address"":""aa"",""Children"":[{""Id"":2,""Name"":""A-01-01"",""Address"":""bb",""Children"":[{""Id"":5,""Name"":""A-01-02-01"",""Address"":""cc""}]},{""Id"":3,""Name"":""A-01-02"",""Address"":""dd""}]},{""Id"":4,""Name"":""B-01"",""Address"":""ee"",""Children"":[{""Id"":6,""Name"":""B-01-01"",""Address"":""ff""}]}]";

    var locations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<Location>>(jsonString.Trim());
```

**ERROR**

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
```

Comment: Your string starts with `\u0001`. Remove that character and it should work.

Comment: The jsonString you've pasted in isn't valid because there's at least a missing double quote after 'bb'

Comment: Is that actually your JSON? Because that's not JSON, it's escaped.

Comment: The error is clear - this isn't a valid JSON string and the problem is caused by the very first character in the string. That `\u0001` sequence is invalid. The code that produces this should be fixed, or the string should be trimmed before it can be parsed

Comment: I've ran your code in "test clean up string". After adding an extra double quote after `bb` the string deserializes correctly for me.

Comment: The trim test code won't even compile because there's a missing double quote after `bb`. It doesn't matter anyway, because the test `jsonString` value *doesn't* contain the invalid character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear, the string isn't valid JSON and the problem is the very first character, `\u0001`.

The "readable" JSON string and the trim test don't contain that character so they can't even reproduce the problem.

[Trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Trim) can't work by itself either. It's job is to remove whitespace but `\u0001` is the SOH (start-of-header) character. That's *not* considered whitespace.

To actually fix the problem, the code that produces this characacter should be fixed so it *doesn't* emit it. If that JSON lines comes from a streaming JSON file that uses SOH as a record delimieter, it should be fixed so it *doesn't* include the record delimiter in the JSON string.

If that's not possible, the [String.Trim(Char[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Trim_System_Char___) overload should be used to remove the SHO character:

```
var locations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString.Trim('\u0001'));
```

Once the SOH character is removed, deserialization works just fine :

```
var jsonString = "\u0001[{\"Id\": 1, \"Name\": \"A-01\", \"Address\": \"aa\", \"Children\": [{\"Id\": 2, \"Name\": \"A-01-01\", \"Address\": \"bb\", \"Children\": [{\"Id\": 5, \"Name\": \"A-01-02-01\", \"Address\": \"cc\"}]}, {\"Id\": 3, \"Name\": \"A-01-02\", \"Address\": \"dd\"}]}, {\"Id\": 4, \"Name\": \"B-01\", \"Address\": \"ee\", \"Children\": [{\"Id\": 6, \"Name\": \"B-01-01\", \"Address\": \"ff\"}]}]";
var cleaned=jsonString.Trim('\u0001');
var locations = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cleaned);
Debug.Assert(locations.Count==2);

var address=(JValue)locations[1]["Children"][0]["Address"];
Debug.Assert(String.Equals(address.Value,"ff"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dai say, there is  "\u0001" character (see [description](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0001/index.htm)). I think you copy it from somwehere and don't need it, so you can just remove it:

```
  var str =
                "\u0001[{\"Id\": 1, \"Name\": \"A-01\", \"Address\": \"aa\", \"Children\": [{\"Id\": 2, \"Name\": \"A-01-01\", \"Address\": \"bb\", \"Children\": [{\"Id\": 5, \"Name\": \"A-01-02-01\", \"Address\": \"cc\"}]}, {\"Id\": 3, \"Name\": \"A-01-02\", \"Address\": \"dd\"}]}, {\"Id\": 4, \"Name\": \"B-01\", \"Address\": \"ee\", \"Children\": [{\"Id\": 6, \"Name\": \"B-01-01\", \"Address\": \"ff\"}]}]";
            var unescapeStr = str.Replace("\u0001", String.Empty);
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<Location>>(unescapeStr);
```

Character "\u0001" shouldn't be in your string at all, not only at start, so you have to remove it from all string using Replace not Trim

Second problem in your test code. When you copy\past string with some scpecial characters Visual Studio ask you, do you want to to escape it, and if you say "yes", you can have escaped twice characters

So try to use for test a string from example above